# Downloading the contents of a python script from a web server in a python script?

Tags: python

I will try word this better, I have a python chat server I retrieve the variable from the python script and echo it in the clients connecting script, but I don't want to distribute the script with the header file and all the other variables, can I include it from a web server? like  Php's
    $var = file_get_contents"http://example.com/includeme.txt"? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many ways to download files in python. Search and pick one!

Comment: Yeh thanks! really helpful!

Comment: Read about Requests library http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/